# If an effect allows you to roll an additional damage die on a critical hit, can you choose the die?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, attack

Let’s say I am playing a Half-Orc Ranger. The Ranger, we’ll call him Bob, fights with a dagger. Bob is fighting a monster and has cast hunters mark on the monster. Bob rolls to hit, and gets a natural 20. The Savage Attacks feature states

> When you score a critical hit with a melee weapon attack, you can roll one of the weapon’s damage dice one additional time and add it to the extra damage of the critical hit.

The damage dealt is the 1d4 of the dagger, plus the 1d6 from the Hunters Mark (doubles to 2d4 + 2d6), plus an additional die from Savage Attacks. Can Bob choose to have the additional die be a d6, or does it have to be a d4? I always read it as “one of the weapon’s damage dice” meaning any die that was being rolled for damage, but my friend thinks that it means the *weapons* damage die, in this case a d4. Which interpretation is right?